# Implement async abstract method synchronously

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an abstract Python class that defined an abstract async method:

```
class ConversionResultsReporter(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    async def report(
        self, conversion_spec: ConversionSpec, results: Sequence[PositiveFloat]
    ) -> None:
        pass
```

I'd like to implement a derived class where the implementation is synchronous, doesn't need to use  `await` - for simplicity let's say it should do print "Hello World" and exit, how would it be written?

Comment: Well, have you tried just to define a regular method instead of coroutine?

Comment: Asynchronous code tends to be viral.  To call it, you have to be asynchronous.  This question has been asked several times, and there are no slam-dunk solutions.

Comment: @OlvinRoght the abstract method needs to return an awaitable since derived classes might need to perform async IO, e.g. write report to a database. However not all derived classes perform async IO, so I'd like to know how to implement them to return an awaitable that already has a result.